# Cover penetrating powers in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Certain powers in Mass Effect 3 are able to penetrate cover such as Shockware and Smash.  These powers are incredibly useful for spamming enemies without exposing yourself to damage.

Are there other powers in Mass Effect 3 that have similar properties?

Comment: not a cover per se, but some sniper rifles (and also the mods) will give them cover penetrating abilities

Answer (score 2):

I believe any power that has a radius when used can penetrate cover.

some that come to mind are:

- Reave
- Incinerate
- Biotic Strike
- Electric Slash (?)

Comment: just a quick note, I don't think biotic charge counts in that aspect. Yes; you ignore all objects in between you and the enemy, but if in order to cast biotic charge the enemy needs to be visible (at least partially), so if there is an enemy hiding behind a box you will not be able to charge.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more I can think of:

- Shadow strike
- Annihilation Field
- Singularity (it does not go through the cover but if you have a good radius on this skill enemies behind cover will get sucked in)